# Where clause on a domain service call

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have a problem when using LINQ to set a where clause on a query in a domain service call.

If I don't set a where clause it works just fine and I get my result back in my completed event (I have only implemented the eventhandler for the completed event to demonstrate my issue here).

```
LoadOperation<User> load = 
  _Context.Load(_Context.GetUsersQuery());
load.Completed += (se, ea) => 
  MyList.ItemsSource = load.Entities.FirstOrDefault();
```

If I put a where clause on the query I simply get an empty list. And the where clause should return 1 row :)

```
LoadOperation<User> load = 
  _Context.Load(_Context.GetUsersQuery().Where(f => f.UserID == UserID));
load.Completed += (se, ea) => 
  MyList.ItemsSource = load.Entities.FirstOrDefault();
```

Any feedback would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK I don't believe it is possible to put the where clause on RIA Services queries like that. You need to implement a method in your service that takes the UserID and puts the where clause on the query in the service.

Here is an example from [Brad Abram's blog series on the subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/10/27/index-for-business-apps-example-for-silverlight-3-rtm-and-net-ria-services-july-update.aspx):

```
public IQueryable<SuperEmployee> GetSuperEmployee(int employeeID)
{
    return Context.GetEmployees().ToList()
          .Where(emp => emp.EmployeeID == employeeID).AsQueryable();

}
```

Comment: can you tell me what will be the query if employeeID is replaced IList<int> employeeIds and I want to find all emp.employeeID  in employeeIds...I hope I was clear with my question

Comment: I think you should post this question as a question, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webapps/archive/2013/01/24/passing-multiple-values-in-a-where-clause-when-calling-ria-services-from-silverlight.aspx)

The "in" is not a valid syntax when calling RIA services. However, you can build a predicate expression that does exactly what "in" would do.

Usage:

```
var ids = new[] { 10, 20,30};
var inExpression = BuiltInExpression (ids);

EntityQuery<Product> listQuery = 
  ProductContext.GetProductsQuery().Where(inExpression);
```

Supporting code:

```
static Expression<Func<Product, bool>> BuiltInExpression(int[] ids) 
{ 
 var inputExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Product), "input"); 
 var valueExpression = Expression.Property(inputExpression, s_propertyInfo); 
 var inExpression = 
 ids 
 .Aggregate( 
 default(Expression), 
 (acc, v) => 
 { 
  var vExpression = Expression.Constant(v, typeof(int?)); 
  var compareExpression = Expression.Equal(valueExpression, vExpression); 
  if (acc == null) 
  { 
   return compareExpression; 
  } 
  return Expression.OrElse(acc, compareExpression); 
 }); 

 inExpression = inExpression ?? Expression.Constant(true); 
 return Expression.Lambda<Func<Product, bool>>( 
  inExpression, 
  inputExpression 
 );

 return inExpression;

}
```